# How can I disable Hyper-V using windows powershell?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, virtualization, hyper-v

I know there a lot of questions on this but after reading and trying a few of the solutions I can't seem to find solve/understand my problem any better.

I'm trying to run VMware work station, but on set up I get the error: Hyper-v or device/credential guard enabled. After opening the powershell and running systeminfo a hyper visor has been detected.

The first solution I tried to disable this, was to use the control panel and turn windows features on or off. Only when I open it I don't get the options I expect. The post I read: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3204980/virtualization-applications-do-not-work-together-with-hyper-v-device-g said there would be an expandable hyper-v folder. On my panel there is no such folder, I just have a single non expandable folder titled: windows hyperverisor platform which is unchecked

[image]

I Then tried a running the powershell as an administrator and using the following command: `Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All`

But this resulted in the following error: `Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V-All is unknown.`

I then read another post about still having Network adaptors form the hyper-v kind but I'm new to fiddling around with operating systems etc and I couldn't understand/follow the method.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Sledgehammer to crack a walnut, but perhaps try `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All` so it's in a known good state, and then `Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All`. You'll need a reboot after the `enable` if there are any system changes.

Comment: The enable doesn't work, it raises the following error `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V-All is unknown.`

Comment: Windows Defender Core Isolation can also steal the resources needed for virtualisation.

Comment: One solution to this problem is to upgrade to 2004 and the current version of VMWARE Workstation.  However, I suspect, you don’t have Windows 10 Professional so that just patches a symptom of the real problem

Comment: So to use these methods to solve the issue I ideally need windows 10 professional?

Comment: Only windows 10 Pro and Enterprise have the Hyper-V features. VMware should still work fine. Try out `DG_Readiness_Tool_vXX.ps1 -disable` from Microsoft here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337

Answer (score 1):

You have WSL enabled, which basically blocks you Workstation installation. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq
You can either update to 2004 or disable WSL.